# Overlapping bars using matplotlib but want them side by side

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have this code, modeled off the example on the matplotlib website as a side by side barchart comparison, but it seems like they're all superimposed on top of each other.

```
def plotHighestFive(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    groups = 5
    z = []
    for i in range(len(x1)):
        z.append((x1[i], x2[i]))        # making a list of the states

    # plot settings
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    index = np.arange(groups)
    width = 0.35
    opacity = 0.9

    rects1 = plt.bar(index + width, y1, width, alpha = opacity, color = 'c', label = '1999')

    rects2 = plt.bar(index + width, y2, width, alpha = opacity, color = 'r', label = '2017')

    # setting up the plot labels
    plt.xlabel('State')
    plt.ylabel('Number of Deaths per 100,000 Residents')
    plt.title('5 States with the Highest Unintended Overdose Death Rate')
    plt.xticks(index + width/2, z)
    plt.legend()

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

The bars for 1999 vs 2017 rates should be next to each other for the highest rate, then second highest and so on, but the 1999 rates are shown on the 2017 rates.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the example you refer to shifts the bars to `index - width/2` and `index + width/2` respectively.

Comment: You are specifying `index + width` as the x-position for both, hence the overlap

Comment: thank you! I spent way too much time looking at my code to notice that

Comment: Do you know how I would should space 5 bars rather than 2? They keep overlapping